# Every birational map is an isomorphism for algebraic curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, birational-geometry

I am looking for a proof and a counter example:

- A proof of the statement:
  "Every birational map is an isomorphism for algebraic curves".
- A counter example for the above statement in the case of algebraic surfaces.

Many thanks for any help or references.

Comment: Do you know what a blowup is?

Comment: What do you mean with algebraic curve and isomorphism? $t\to (t^2(t-1),(t-1)^2t)$ is an isomorphism from $\Bbb{C}-\{0,1\}$ but not at $0,1$.

Comment: @LouisJaburi Yes I know cursorily what is a blow-up of a singular variety $X$, it's a pair $(\tilde{X},f)$ where $f: \tilde{X}\to X$ is a map and $\tilde{X}$ is a smooth variety

Comment: @reuns By algebraic curve I mean a $\operatorname{dim} =1$ irreducible variety defined as the intersection of 0-loci of some polynomial over a field $k=\overline k$. By isomorphism I mean a bijective morphism of algebraic varieties $f:V \to W$ for instance with $\forall v\in V, f(v)$ verifies the polynomials defining $W$

Comment: @PerelMan Your definition of blow-up is not incorrect. Also, if your algebraic curves are not smooth, then the statement you desire a proof of is also incorrect. Simply take the normalization of a nodal curve, say.

Answer (score 1):

This is covered in Fulton's "Algebraic curves"

- For your first question combine 6.6 Proposition 12 and 7.1 Corollary 3 (your statement as it stands is wrong)
- For your second question you can either check out Problem 6.39 or read about blowups in Section 7.2+7.3

Comment: It seems unnecessarily complicated to use blow-ups -- there are much simpler counterexamples.

Comment: I agree, the one mentioned in Problem 6.39 is easier (namely $\mathbb{P}^1\times \mathbb{P}^1$ and $\mathbb{P}^2$). But I thought for the sake of completeness I should add it, as they are very important in the theory of algebraic surfaces.